# Is there a way I can get value from second row first column value in Mysql to a text box in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to solve this mystery from a lot of time. My knowledge is limited. So I got stuck in here. I need to get the value from the second row first column data (Need to specify the row and column and get the value) to a textbox. Please give an answer even this feel easy. Sorry if it is.

```
 Dim conn As SqlConnection

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE attendance.dateverification SET Count1 = CASE WHEN Today_Date <> current_date THEN Count1 + 1 ELSE Count1 END,
        Count2 = CASE WHEN Today_Date = current_date THEN Count2 + 1 ELSE Count2 END,   
        Today_Date = current_date,
        Subject_selected =@subject WHERE Subject_Name = @subject; SELECT Subject_Name, Today_Date, Count1, Count2 FROM dateverification"

    Try
        conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject", MySqlDbType.VarString, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text

        conn.Open()
        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        rdr.Read()

        TextBox2.Text = rdr("Subject_Name").ToString()
        Label1.Text = rdr("Today_Date").ToString()
        Label2.Text = rdr("Count1").ToString()
        Label3.Text = rdr("Count2").ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `rdr.Read()` again to advance to the next record.

Comment: You mean in another line? rdr.Read() rdr.Read() ? Or rdr.Read() codes rdr.Read() ? BTW Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Tharaka The second one. You call `rdr.Read()` as already done, and then look at the records on the first row, as is already happening. Then call `rdr.Read()` again to advance to the next row, and use more code to process anything you want from that row. You can also put this in a `While` loop to process many rows in a query.

Comment: The SQL lacks any form of ordering; this solution will be fragile at best. Recommend that the SELECT be given a proper WHERE clause, possibly a MAX or other single row guarantee, and be ExecuteScalar'd if it truly is a single column value that is required

Comment: Thank you so much @Joel Thank you again.